# What is the config file format when i use the command ./server start?

Tags: arm64, cadence-workflow

So i can not use the official docker images on arm64 platform, so i compile it on my own pc. but there is a issue when i start it.

Here is the information:

```
[server]# ./server start
2023/08/09 09:32:45 Loading config; env=development,zone=,configDir=./config
```

I have put the file development.yaml from docker container in this folder. but it also shows format error.

```
[root@k8s-node1 server]# ./server start
2023/08/09 09:32:45 Loading config; env=development,zone=,configDir=./config
2023/08/09 09:32:45 Loading configFiles=[./config/development.yaml]
2023/08/09 09:32:45 Config file corrupted.yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field frontend.enableClientVersionCheck not found in type config.Config
  line 4: field history.EnableConsistentQueryByDomain not found in type config.Config
  line 7: field history.enableCrossClusterOperations not found in type config.Config
  line 10: field history.useNewInitialFailoverVersion not found in type config.Config
  line 13: field system.minRetentionDays not found in type config.Config
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, I think you might be missing the .yaml config file located inside the dynamicconfig/ directory: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/config/dynamicconfig/development.yaml